# How can I wire StructureMap with 2 different objects (log4net loggers) of the same interface

Tags: c#, log4net, structuremap, structuremap3

I have a class named `MyClass`, which uses two different loggers named `Logger1` and `Logger2`. I use log4net for logging, and want to use StructureMap for DI.

Without StructureMap, my class would look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger1"); // Loggers are configured in a config file
    private static readonly ILog Logger2 = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger2");

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        Logger1.Info("did something");
        ...
        Logger2.Info("need to log this elsewhere");
    }
 }
```

Introducing DI, with StructureMap (using v3.0.3), I would make the loggers instance members, and inject them into the constructor, like this:
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly ILog Logger1;
        private readonly ILog Logger2;

```
    myClass(ILog logger1, ILog logger2)
    {
        this.Logger1 = logger1;
        this.Logger2 = logger2;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        Logger1.Info("did something");
        ...
        Logger2.Info("need to log this elsewhere");
    }
 }
```

The thing is, I cannot get StructureMap to wire this up for me properly. I tried wiring the loggers like this:

```
For<ILog>.Use(()=> LogManager.GetLogger("Logger1")).Named("Logger1");
For<ILog>.Use(()=> LogManager.GetLogger("Logger2")).Named("Logger2");
```

Doing this Gets me empty (unconfigured) loggers). Replacing `Use()` with `Add()` gives my an exception due to not having a default instance registered for ILog.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Is it your intention to write the same information to those two loggers, or do you need to log different information to both loggers?

Comment: Different information to different loggers. I already know that I can have the same info go to different files using different appenders. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following: I created two interfaces as per Rob's advice: `ILogger1` and `ILogger2`. Since the both have the same API, as I need the same *kind of* functionality from them, they both inherit from the same interface - though **not** `log4net.ILog` as per Steven's advice:

```
interface IMyLog
{
    void Info(object message);
    void Info(string format, params object[] args);
}

interface ILogger1 : IMyLog { }
interface ILogger2 : IMyLog { }
```

Also, since the implementation of this API is the same for my needs, I have one concrete class `MyLogger`, implementing both `ILogger1` and `ILogger2`. If I ever need the implementations to be different it will be easy for me to have explicit interface implementation, or separate classes. Only `My Logger` takes a dependency on log4net, as it uses it for its implementation:

```
enum LoggerType { Logger1, Logger2 }

internal class MyLogger : ILogger1, ILogger2
{
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public MyLogger(LoggerType loggerName)
    {
        switch (loggerName)
        {
            case LoggerType.Logger1:
                _log = LogManager.GetLogger("first-log");
                break;
            case LoggerType.Logger2:
                _log = LogManager.GetLogger("second-log");
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid logger name", "loggerName");
        }
    }

    public void Info(object message)
    {
        _log.Info(message);
    }

    public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.InfoFormat(format, args);
    }
}
```

In order to register it with **StructureMap**, I used the following code in the registry:

```
For<ILogger1>().Use<MyLogger>().Ctor<LoggerType>("loggerName").Is(LoggerType.Logger1).Singleton();   // I want only one logger per type
For<ILogger2>().Use<MyLogger>().Ctor<LoggerType>("loggerName").Is(LoggerType.Logger2).Singleton();
```

It all works wonderfully. So, thanks to Steven and Rob for their advice. I really learned something. I wish I could upvote an answer and a response more than once.

So, to summarize, I:

- Created a separate interface for each kind of logger (even saying it now sounds intuitive).
- Created a base interface for the logger interfaces, because **for my needs** they have the same API (YMMV)
- Created one concrete logger adapter that implements both interfaces because that suits **my needs** (YMMV again)
- Share the implementation of the interfaces' API, for the above reasons
- Registered each interface to create a concrete logger with a different type passed in the constructor
- configured the concrete logger with log4net using a [Factory Method](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) to determine which logger to use

Answer (score 4):

If the loggers perform different roles then I would create two interfaces inheriting from ILog to reflect this. That way you would have no problem configuring StructureMap to handle them.

Comment: OP uses log4net for logging, I think it's not possible to inherit from ILog.

Comment: The interface would just allow the OP to target named logger instances as they would like to do.

Comment: @kpa6uk, the OP should not let his application depend directly on this framework defined interface anyway. Interfaces should be defined by the client.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. While I can inherit from the `ILog` interface, When I try to configure the Registry as such: `For<IExecutionLog>().Use(()=> LogManager.GetLogger("execution-log"));`, it says that **The type 'log4net.ILog' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression<TPluginType>.Use<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T>>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'log4net.ILog' to 'StructureMapAndLog4Net.IExecutionLog'**.

Comment: @Steven - So should I instead have a **single** logger abstraction that can log to either logger? Say have a method `public void Info(string loggerName, string message) { ... }`? Where the `loggerName` would of course send me to one logger or the other?

Comment: @AssafStone, I agree with Rob that you need two abstractions, since they have a different function in your application. What I don't agree with is inheriting from ILog, since 1. that still forces your app to take a dependenvy on log4net and 2. that ILog abstraction is one big Interface Segregation Principle violation. Define your own two narrow abstractions, ideally with just one method.

Answer (score 0):

As an alterative to the answers above, this can be solved exclusively in StructureMap (and I believe works for the SM version used in the question).  You can tell StructureMap exactly how to build `MyClass` by also including the following in a Registry.

```
For<MyClass>().Use(x => new MyClass(x.GetInstance<ILog>("Logger1"), x.GetInstance<ILog>("Logger2")));
```